# There are (also) several other advantages have been observed?

Tags: sentence-construction

This is my situation: at the last sentence, I listed an example which shows an advantage of my model. Then I want to write a sentence to say something like:

"Moreover, there are several other advantages have been observed. For example...."

But, I feel so uncomfortable when I read this sentence...but I don't know how to improve it... Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: *...there are several other advantages **that** have been observed.* Either include ***that***, or delete ***there are***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, it looks uncomfortable because it uses two predicates at once. Pick one:
"Moreover, there are several other advantages."
"Moreover, several other advantages have been observed."